# Only insert data WHERE NOT EXISTS not working

Tags: mysql, pdo

How can I change this query to only insert the information, if the information is not already there?

I've tried adding WHERE NOT EXISTS, but it stops the query working. Can anyone help me out, maybe I'm typing it wrong.

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_blocking SET active = '0' WHERE blocking = :user AND user = :who LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use `INSERT` statement instead?
**EDIT**
With a `SELECT` you can check if the information is there, and use `UPDATE` or `INSERT` accordingly.